# Else condition w/popover doesn't work for the first input/click, but works fine on subsequent clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The only issue with my popovers, is that the “else” condition does not work for the very first search input/click. However, the “if” condition does work.  Everything after the first input/click works fine. Any thoughts or suggestions??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <style>
  #closeBtn, #searchBtn{
   background-color: #180D01;
     color: #fed136; 
   }
  #closeBtn, #searchBtn:hover{
   color: #180D01;
     background-color: #fed136; 
   }

 </style>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search a country!</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter A Country">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
  <!--==============SEARCH BUTTON ===============-->
    <a href="#" tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchBtn" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" >Search</a>
  </div>
</div>




 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  //CASE SENSITIVE!!!
  var validCountriesArray = [
   "Sweden", 
   "France", 
   "Germany",
   "United States", "usa", 
   "Austria", 
   "Switzerland", 
   "Denmark", 
   "Great Britain", "england", "UK", "U.K.",
   "West Germany", 
   "United Team of Germany", 
   "Soviet Union", "Russia",
   "Netherlands", 
   "Spain"];
   



 function invalidPopoverShow(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement: "right",
            trigger: "focus",
            content: "Choose a valid country that had Dressage/Equestrain participants in the Olympics! (Click anywhere to make popover disappear)",
        }); 
 }
 function invalidPopoverHide(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
 }
 ////========================

  $('#searchBtn').click(function() {
   var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
   console.log(searchTerm);
   //clears text in search box
    for (var i=0; i<validCountriesArray.length; i++){
     if (searchTerm.toLowerCase() == validCountriesArray[i].toLowerCase()){
      //.toLowerCase unifies & converts user input to lowercase
       console.log("Good pick!" + searchTerm);
       invalidPopoverHide();  
     }
     else {
      invalidPopoverShow(); 
      
     }
    }
    $("#search").val(""); 
  });
 //=====WHY DOESNT THE FIRST invalid SEARCHterm WORK??????=====//
 });     

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <style>
  #closeBtn, #searchBtn{
   background-color: #180D01;
     color: #fed136; 
   }
  #closeBtn, #searchBtn:hover{
   color: #180D01;
     background-color: #fed136; 
   }

 </style>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Search a country!</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Enter A Country">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
  <!--==============SEARCH BUTTON ===============-->
    <a href="#" tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchBtn" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" >Search</a>
  </div>
</div>




 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  //CASE SENSITIVE!!!
  var validCountriesArray = [
   "Sweden", 
   "France", 
   "Germany",
   "United States", "usa", 
   "Austria", 
   "Switzerland", 
   "Denmark", 
   "Great Britain", "england", "UK", "U.K.",
   "West Germany", 
   "United Team of Germany", 
   "Soviet Union", "Russia",
   "Netherlands", 
   "Spain"];
   



 function invalidPopoverShow(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            placement: "right",
            trigger: "focus",
            content: "Choose a valid country that had Dressage/Equestrain participants in the Olympics! (Click anywhere to make popover disappear)",
        }); 
 }
 function invalidPopoverHide(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
 }
 ////========================

  $('#searchBtn').click(function() {
   var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
   console.log(searchTerm);
   //clears text in search box
    for (var i=0; i<validCountriesArray.length; i++){
     if (searchTerm.toLowerCase() == validCountriesArray[i].toLowerCase()){
      //.toLowerCase unifies & converts user input to lowercase
       console.log("Good pick!" + searchTerm);
       invalidPopoverHide();  
     }
     else {
      invalidPopoverShow(); 
      
     }
    }
    $("#search").val(""); 
  });
 //=====WHY DOESNT THE FIRST invalid SEARCHterm WORK??????=====//
 });     

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is there 2 sets of code here? see [mcve]

Comment: Been trying to fix this for 40 minutes, but it's like it not gonna happen. I will try to point you in the right direction: You have the popup **initialization** in the "else". You need to initialize it after the page load so its ready to use. Then you either show or hide it with your code (but for this you need `trigger:"manual"` option in the initialization, because a click in the button triggers the popover; oh and also to code your own "hide on click anywhere"). Also you need to redesign your loop to not trigger the show/hide functions for each check. Only trigger at the final.

Comment: @yuriy636: Thanks so much for trying.  I will try that!